# How to save multiples refs into one document in MongoDB with mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'am trying to save multiple tags to a specific product I just created. I succeeded to push the tags into the product collection, but when I try to save it then I got an error : Can't save() the same doc multiple times in parallel.

I'am using mongoDB, node and Mongoose.

Here are my Schemas

```
var tagSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    tagname: String,
});

var tag = mongoose.model('Tag', tagSchema);


var Item = new Schema({
    title : String,
    description : String,
    price : Number,
    tags:  [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Tag"
    }]
});

var product = mongoose.model('Product', Item);
```

And here my code in node.js when I try to create a new product with the associated tags in the DB (coming from a HTML form)

```
product.create(req.body.product, function(err, newitem){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            }else{

             console.log(req.body.tags); // gives ["fun","cheap"] from the form
             req.body.tags.forEach(function(newtag){
             tag.findOne({tagname : newtag},function(err, finalcast){


             newitem.tags.push(finalcast); 
             console.log(newitem); // gives the product with the tag collections in it.

               });
              newitem.save(); // error Can't save() the same doc multiple times in parallel.
              console.log(newitem); // the product collection has an empty tags[] 

               });


                 res.redirect("/");

            }

        });
```

How can I save the tags collection direcly in the product all at once ? Is is better to create the product and then insert the tags one by one using push ?

Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be because you trying to push object rather than _id by doing

```
newitem.tags.push(finalcast);
```

Try to push object's _id like this:

```
newitem.tags.push(finalcast._id);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it has something to do with Asynchrone JS but i'am not sure. The loop doesn't seems to be a good Idea there...

How can I easily save multiples tags documents into one product document ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok after hours of working on it i found a solution. I really don't know if it's a good way to do it but it works. I insert a if() inside the forEach to save only when the forEach loop is done:

```
 req.body.tags.forEach(function(newtag, index){
                    tag.findOne({tagname : newtag},function(err, finalcast){

                    newitem.tags.push(finalcast); 

                    if(index + 1 == req.body.tags.length){
                    newitem.save();
                    res.redirect("/");

                    }
               });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are performing them all at once in your `forEach` loop which makes it hard to know when the database operation is done. It also means that you are triggering `res.redirect` before the operation has actually finished. I would use async/await for this. I wrote this pretty quickly and haven't tested it but I think it should work:

```
const tagSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  tagname: String
})

const Tag = mongoose.model('Tag', tagSchema)

const itemSchema = new Schema({
  title: String,
  description: String,
  price: Number,
  tags: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Tag"
  }]
})

const Product = mongoose.model('Product', itemSchema)


const createProduct = async (req, res) => {
  const { tags, product } = req.body

  try {
    const product = new Product(product)

    for (let i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
      const tagName = tags[i]
      const existingTag = await Tag.findOne({ tagname: tagName })

      if (!existingTag) {
        await new Tag({ tagname: tagName}).save()
      }
    }

    await product.save()

    res.redirect('/') 

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```

In the code I've done a couple of things:

- Use async/await in order to do one thing at a time instead of doing them synchronously.
- Cleaned up the code: Indentation etc was a little messy (I've used StandardJS style)
- Used pascal case for models since they are object constructors. There's a reason why models start with a capital letter.
- Used for loop instead of forEach because forEach doesn't work with async.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It will help me a lot to understand how it works.

Comment: Glad I could help! Don't forget to upvote / mark as correct answer if you're happy with the answer.